# Lenovo S540, "The system is running in low graphics mode"

Tags: intel-graphics

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10 through the installer on a Lenovo Thinkpad S540. I had no problems with the graphical installer.

However, after rebooting, X doesn't start. I just get a "The system is running in low graphics mode" error.

The graphics card is a "Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller".

I've tried updating from the X-swat PPA as per instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/218095/258364. Made no difference.

It also fails if I reboot in "failsafe" mode.

Any ideas on what I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Check out `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` if `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` nomodeset exists then delete it and run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: @kenn There is no `nomodeset` option specified in `/etc/default/grub'`(also, gedit doesn't work so well when X doesn't start).

Comment: Did you read answer of sccott here http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/218095#218095

Comment: @kenn -- Yes. I mentioned that explicitly in my question.

Comment: I mean if you applied `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` ?

Comment: Removing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` doesn't make any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: I ended up resolving this via this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293264/the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-12-04

Comment: I'm glad that you fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on my ThinkPad S540 after installed Ubuntu 13.10. The solution for me was to create `/etc/X11/xorg.config` file which was somehow missing:

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.config.failsafe /etc/X11/xorg.config
```

and then restart.

If you stuck on "The system is running in low graphics mode" page and `Ctrl+Alt+F1` does not work to enter terminal mode then try to play with `Enter` / `Tab` / `Windows+Left` / `Windows+Right` shortcuts until the terminal mode appears ;)